# Download youtube videos with flash

Tags: actionscript-3, air, youtube, download

I'm new to flash, but I understand most concepts of it and had great progress so far.
I was wondering how hard it would be to say download a youtube video and what components/functions I would have to use. I know its possible since I've seen an Adobe Air app that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Youtube Chromeless Player](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html)!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what purpose you have with your YouTube application. Depending on what you want to do you can go several different ways

- If you want to use the in-built flash functionality, use the flash API. http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html
- The best solution (i think) is to use the JS api, it has a lot of tweaking options for playlists, start/ stop function, cusumization (such as the chromeless player mentioned above). Available here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html